# SQL SELECT statement rolling 5,10 day per different criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a SELECT postgres sql statement to create a rolling sum of the item_.amount column with specific conditions. I would like the Rolling sum fields with the following criteria.
5 day , sell, item A
10 day , buy, item B
10 day, sell

The work that I have done is the following :

First off , in db fiddle I have two tables : 1 table with item_ transactions and 1 table with the date fields.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80fcb5654ead862f7b057c76425e91ca

I have combined the tables to

```
select date_actual,transaction_date 
FROM date LEFT JOIN item_ ON item_.transaction_date=date.date_actual
ORDER BY date.date_actual DESC
```

I explain the Rolling columns (5 Day or 10 Day) below. I need to also consider the item_name of "A/B" and the transaction_type of "buy/sell".

So for example Rolling_A_sell_5day in the top row 2021-4-10 is 76. 76 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0. The above calculation does not include the 94 because are looking for "A" and the "sell" column so it only includes the 76 and the rest of the rows are 0.
[image]

Likewise for the Rolling_buy_10day in row 2021-4-10 is 94. 0 + 0 + 0 + 94 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0

[image]

For the output image table, I have tried creating a SQL statement such as this but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
    SELECT 
      t1.Id
     ,t1.transaction_date
     ,t1.amount
     ,SUM(t2.amount) as Rolling10DayQt
   FROM item_ t1
      CROSS JOIN(
          SELECT *
          FROM item_ a
          WHERE a.id=t1.Id 
             AND (a.transaction_date > DATEADD(DAY,-10,t1.transaction_date) AND a.transaction_date <= t1.transaction_date) ) t2
   GROUP BY t1.Id ,t1.transaction_date ,t1.amount
```

The OUTPUT TABLE should look like this :
[image]

Comment: Sample data and readable desired results would make it much easier to understand the question.  I also wonder if the data can be simplified to get rid of unnecessary columns.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have cleaned up my original question, cut down the sample data. Hopefully it is more clear now. The number of columns/fields in the output table cannot be reduced as the date.actual_date field comes from the date table. And the item_,date,_name,_transaction,amount all are needed for the calculation of the three rolling columns. Of the 3 rolling columns, my question is the way to configure the SQL statement to obtain one rolling column. The other two I can derive myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by the following a WINDOW statement OVER and RANGE BETWEEN statement :

```
                                 SUM((SELECT quantity as B_alloc
                              WHERE item_name='B')) OVER (
                                 ORDER by date.date_actual 
                                 RANGE BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                             ) as CUM_inv_B,
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c270837503bc96aa790d169bbe87d2bb